# Tweetsharp: all tweets that has ever existed indexed? how can i show older tweets in my application?

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetsharp

I have created a application where i store tweets to a database. For example i search for a word and tweets come up containing that word and then i store them to the database. I recently read that twitter have indexed all their tweets, so you can trace back to the first tweets ever posted. now i want to create sort of a condition, where i want to get tweets containing a word and from a certain time period.

example:

search word: hello
from: 2012-01-03
to: 2014-05-07

is this possible to fix in tweetsharp?

i suspect that i need to declare something here but i dont know what though:

TwitterSearchResult inc = service.Search(new SearchOptions { Q = textBox2.Text, Count = 10000 });
IEnumerable status = inc.Statuses;

Please help. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

```
public TwitterStatus searchTweets(string targetName, string keyword,DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> list = twitter.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() { ScreenName = targetName }); 
        foreach (TwitterStatus item in list)
        {
            if (item.Text.Contains(keyword) && item.CreatedDate>start&&item.CreatedDate<end)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I feel this is what you were wanting. It grabs the tweets from a designated target (grabbing from the account linked with the access token does not need a target), and grabs the first item found that meets the criteria. To get more of the items, simply make a list and add to it for every found item and return that.